# How to separate row values with a delimiter into individual rows?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Currently, there are values in my database that look like this:

| Name | ItemID |
| --- | --- |
| bob's burgers | 101,102,103 |
| the clam | 201,202 |
| moe's pub | 301,302,303,304 |

is there a way for this to be broken down where the itemID with the delimiter "," is separated into its own row?

Final table:

| Name | ItemID |
| --- | --- |
| bob's burgers | 101 |
| bob's burgers | 102 |
| bob's burgers | 103 |
| the clam | 201 |
| the clam | 202 |
| moe's pub | 301 |
| moe's pub | 302 |
| moe's pub | 303 |
| moe's pub | 304 |

Answer (score 0):

Use [SPLIT_TO_TABLE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_to_table.html) function:

```sql
WITH sample_data AS (
    SELECT Name, ItemID
      FROM VALUES 
            ('bob''s burgers',  '101,102,103'),
            ('the clam',    '201,202'),
            ('moe''s pub',  '301,302,303,304') AS v(Name, ItemID)
)
SELECT s.Name, i.VALUE AS ItemID
  FROM sample_data AS s
  FULL OUTER JOIN TABLE(SPLIT_TO_TABLE(s.ItemID, ',')) AS i;
```